# Desktop application for PC or MAC

Tags: wpf, cross-platform

I've had a quick look on the interweb and can't seem to easily find the answer to my question which is, what do I need to do differently to make a desktop application, WPF, function on both PC and MAC environments? I suppose I could buy a mac and try to run an app I've written but seems a bit expensive?

There are comments that WPF on mac is a no-go. I could convert to Silverlight with some effort but my question now is what would you develop a desktop app in for both PC and MAC, my guess is poor old WinForms? If so would the pitfalls simply be directory structure / accessing logged in user from WIN32 API commands, et cetera?

Comment: We need more information to answer that. What language are you writing the code in? What toolkits are you using? Is it a GUI or command-line application (I'm guessing GUI from your use of 'desktop' but specificity is appreciated)?

Comment: Sorry, but neither the WinAPI nor Winforms are available on OS X!

Answer (score 0):

You can't run WPF on a mac.

The best you can get is Silverlight and its suitability depends on your needs.

Do you need OS level access?

Answer (score 0):

As Scartag says, WPF is not compatible with OS X. However you might to consider Mono, which allows you to write cross-platform applications in C#. There are several [GUI toolkits](http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits) to choose from, but none are implementations of WPF. Further info on Mono/WPF can be found [here](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF).

Comment: In response to your edit - Mono does have a Winforms implementation, among other options.